# SSAS - Format String not applied

Tags: ssas

Having issues getting the Format String applied. Running SSDT in VS2013 and deploying to SQL Server 2014.

**Settings**

[image: Calculated Member Settings]

**Result**

[image: Results]

Excel also doesn't display the selected format. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Answer found on technet.

> This is because the new cube browser control used in SSDT (unlike the old cube browser used for earlier versions of BIDS/SSAS) does not display the formatted value, it just displays the raw, unformatted value only.

Testing in Excel reveiled format strings being applied.

Source:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/171fa5b0-014b-4a64-a590-9c3d2392b528/ssas-2012-measure-formatting?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Answer (score 0):

The FormatString setting can be viewed properly when you export your SSDT cube browser to Microsoft Excel. The older BIDS (SQL 2008) used to display properly such values, but this feature got lost in newer versions (the latter only display the DataType values without any formatting mask.)