# SSAS/SSRS : no percentage format?

Tags: reporting-services, format, report, ssas, cube

I want to format a percentage in SSAS and SSRs but both fail.
In SSAS the value I want to format is a named calculation :

[image: named calculation], but the format isn't applied.

According to [this post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253603/ssas-format-string-not-applied), there was a regression in visual studio (SSDT).

In SSRS, the following MDX request:

```
with member  [Measures].Pct as  [Measures].[Pourcentage Patients par hôpital et âge], FORMAT_STRING="Percent"

SELECT {[Measures].[VPARCOURS Nombre], [Measures].[Pct]    } ON 0,
{  strtoset(@Hospital) * {   [Dim Age].[catage1].[Cat Age1] - [Dim Age].[catage1].[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER  
}  } ON 1
FROM [BDD PBM]
```

gives the expected result but not formatted (e.g. 6.89544172413793).

Is there a way to get, in the cube or in the reports, the value in a format like "6.90%"?

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would be to **not** format the value in SSAS and just return the value `0.0689544172413793`

You could then set the textbox format property in SSRS to `p2` to give display as a percentage.